# Contar dos días (ejemplo: miércoles y viernes) entre un rango de fecha que sale de una tabla en SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

El reporte que estoy realizando es sobre el agendamiento de citas de los médicos y debo sacar la disponibilidad de la agenda. Ejemplo: en este caso específico lo estoy haciendo con un médico que solo trabaja los miércoles y los viernes en la mañana; la agenda está del 18/08/2023 hasta el 30/08/2023. Revisando el calendario hay 2 miércoles y 2 viernes; teniendo en cuenta que los miércoles solo trabaja de 7:45 a 11:45 y los viernes de 8 a 10 citas de 15min, los miércoles atiende 16 citas y los viernes 8 citas, y en total tiene 48 citas disponibles. Con esta información lo que debo mostrar es la multiplicación de los días para sacar la totalidad en la disponibilidad. Las fechas salen de una tabla y debe ser un reporte subido a REPORT BUILDER para que ellos estén generando el reporte de acuerdo a las fechas.

En el momento tengo el siguiente SCRIPT que aún no me funciona:

```
SELECT A.MMCODM
      ,A.AgeCsc
      ,CONVERT(VARCHAR,B.AgeFchIni,23) 'FECHA INICIAL'
      ,CONVERT(VARCHAR,B.AgeFchFin,23) 'FECHA FINAL'
      ,CASE WHEN A.MMDia='4' THEN 'Miercoles' 
            WHEN A.MMDia='6' then'Viernes' 
            END dias
      ,MMHorIni
      ,MMHorFin
      ,datediff(minute,MMHorIni,MMHorFin) minutos 
      ,MMTieAte 
      ,(datediff(minute,MMHorIni,MMHorFin)/MMTieAte) citas
      ,dbo.udf_DayOfWeek(B.AgeFchFin,B.AgeFchIni,MMDia) Dias
      
FROM MAEMED2  AS A 
LEFT JOIN MaeMedAge AS B ON A.MMCODM=B.MMCODM AND A.AgeCsc=B.AgeCsc
WHERE A.MMCODM='M0162' AND A.AgeCsc='67' ---AND C.MedFchExc BETWEEN '20230818' AND '20230831' 
GROUP BY A.MMCODM, A.AgeCsc, B.AgeFchIni, B.AgeFchFin, MMDia, MMHorIni, MMHorFin, MMTieAte
```

Así es como aparece en el momento:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

`dbo.udf_DayOfWeek(B.AgeFchFin,B.AgeFchIni,MMDia)` <--- El siguiente código lo utilicé de lo siguiente:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udf_DayOfWeek(@dtDate1 DATETIME, @dtDate2 DATETIME, @dayOfWeek int)
RETURNS int
AS
 BEGIN
 DECLARE @Total INT
 SET @Total = 0
 WHILE @dtDate2 > @dtDate1
  BEGIN
   IF DATEPART(dw, @dtDate1) = @dayOfWeek
     SET @Total = @Total + 1
     SET @dtDate1 = DATEADD(dd, 1, @dtDate1)
     CONTINUE
  END
  RETURN (@Total)
END
```

Todo esto fue para poder hacer el conteo de los días.

Comment: y vos estas seguro que datepart te devuelve el nombre del dia de esa forma?

Comment: @gbianchi Hola, en lo que pude investigar el datepart es quien logra evaluar una fecha y devolver un intervalo de tiempo especifico, por eso lo utilice, pero no, igual no estoy segura...

Comment: de la documentacion "The specific part of the date argument for which DATEPART will return an integer".. o sea.. devuelve un entero... y te recomiendo leer [esta parte](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#week-and-weekday-datepart-arguments) no me queda claro que el miercoles sea el dia 4, salvo, que empieces en domingos a contar, que tampoco lo tengo tan claro...

Comment: Hola, en realidad si necesitaría que devolviera un entero, así podría mirar la disponibilidad de la agenda,  con respecto a lo otro es que la base que estoy manejando empieza a contar el domingo como número 1, lunes 2, martes 3, miércoles 4, a si es como clasificaron los días para los agendamientos.

Answer (score 0):

Yo cambiaría la función `udf_DayOfWeek` de esta manera:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udf_DayOfWeek(@dtDate1 datetime, @dtDate2 datetime, @dayOfWeek tinyint)
RETURNS int AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Total int = 0
    WHILE 1 + (DATEPART(dw, @dtDate1) + @@DATEFIRST - 1) % 7 <> @dayOfWeek AND @dtDate1 <= @dtDate2
        SELECT @dtDate1 = DATEADD(dd, 1, @dtDate1)
    WHILE @dtDate1 <= @dtDate2
        SELECT @dtDate1 = DATEADD(dd, 7, @dtDate1), @Total = @Total + 1
    RETURN @Total
END
```

Por un lado, mediante `1 + (DATEPART(dw, @dtDate1) + @@DATEFIRST - 1) % 7` te aseguras que siempre el domingo será 1 y el sábado 7, sea cual sea el idioma utilizado (`set language spanish` o `set language english`). Con el primer `WHILE` llega al primer día coincidente (si no lo estabas ya), y con el segundo los totaliza y salta de 7 en 7 días.